# Gerrit Replication to gitlab failed

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, gerrit, gitlab-ci

When I configure the replication from Gerrit to gitlab, the replication_log keep reporting:

```
[2016-10-10 09:36:07,517] [d0b90d12] Missing repository created; retry replication to git@mo-3394cf6e0.mo.sap.corp:CI_prep_group/sprmvc-ui5.git
[2016-10-10 09:37:07,517] [d0b90d12] Replication to git@mo-3394cf6e0.mo.sap.corp:CI_prep_group/sprmvc-ui5.git started...
[2016-10-10 09:37:07,874] [d0b90d12] Created remote repository: git@mo-3394cf6e0.mo.sap.corp:CI_prep_group/sprmvc-ui5.git
[2016-10-10 09:37:07,874] [d0b90d12] Missing repository created; retry replication to git@mo-3394cf6e0.mo.sap.corp:CI_prep_group/sprmvc-ui5.git
[2016-10-10 09:38:07,875] [d0b90d12] Replication to git@mo-3394cf6e0.mo.sap.corp:CI_prep_group/sprmvc-ui5.git started...
[2016-10-10 09:38:08,259] [d0b90d12] Created remote repository: git@mo-3394cf6e0.mo.sap.corp:CI_prep_group/sprmvc-ui5.git
```

My replication.config file:

```
  [remote "sprmvc-ui5"]
    projects = sprmvc-ui5
    url = git@mo-3394cf6e0.mo.sap.corp:CI_prep_group/sprmvc-ui5.git
    push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
    push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
    push = +refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*
    threads = 3
```

My .ssh/config file:

```
Host mo-3394cf6e0.mo.sap.corp
    HostName mo-3394cf6e0.mo.sap.corp
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

Can anyone give me an advice?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by create a new user in gitlab and give it full access to my project, maintain the public key which comes from gerrit server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need for replication? Just put it to the same server where you have GitLab installed.

Install:

```
# install rpm source: the path took through INSTALL file
sudo rpm -i https://gerritforge.com/gerritforge-repo-1-2.noarch.rpm

#install gerrit
sudo yum install -y gerrit
```

Init gerrit configuration (can be run multiple times, options are saved).

Here we **set path to git bare repos and the same path may be specified that gitlab has**.

```
java -jar /var/gerrit/bin/gerrit.war init
```

Launch:

```
java -jar /var/gerrit/bin/gerrit.war daemon --console
```